# Send proposal with signature ends with `ChaincodeId is nill` error in Hyperledger Fabric 2.2 NodeJS client

Tags: node.js, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

This is the flow we need on the backend.

1. First user creates unsigned proposal and the proposal buffer is returned to him.

```
        const proposal = new Endorsement(this.config.chaincodeId, this.channel)

        const user = User.createUser(
            enrollmentId,
            enrollmentId,
            this.config.userMspId,
            certificate
        )

        const identityContext = new IdentityContext(user, this.channel.client)

        const proposalBuffer = proposal.build(identityContext, {
            fcn,
            args,
        })

        const digest = createHash('sha256').update(proposalBuffer).digest('hex')
```

2. Then after user signs digest and creates signature our backend sends signed proposal to endorser:

```
        const signedProposal = {
            signature: Buffer.from(signature, 'base64'),
            proposal_bytes: proposalBuffer,
        }

        const endorser = this.channel.getEndorsers(this.config.userMspId)[0]

        const response = await endorser.sendProposal(
            Buffer.from(JSON.stringify( signedProposal ))
        )
```

`sendProposal` method throws  `ChaincodeId is nil` error.

Anyone knows how we could implement this right?

How do we create the **Buffer** object for the **sendProposal** method parameter?

In my case I created the buffer from stringified json object, how SignedProposal is defined in the Hyperledger Fabric documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I see your code is custom code to send a proposal. Why should you do this? Why not do the easy way by using `fabric-network` lib?

For your question, I found some code in `fabric-network`:

```js
// This is the object that will centralize this endorsement activities
// with the fabric network
const endorsement = channel.newEndorsement(this.contract.chaincodeId);
const proposalBuildRequest = this.newBuildProposalRequest(args);
logger.debug('%s - build and send the endorsement', method);
// build the outbound request along with getting a new transactionId
// from the identity context
endorsement.build(this.identityContext, proposalBuildRequest);
endorsement.sign(this.identityContext);
...
...
else if (this.endorsingOrgs) {
   logger.debug('%s - user has assigned endorsing orgs %s', method, this.endorsingOrgs);
   const flatten = (accumulator, value) => {
        accumulator.push(...value);
        return accumulator;
   };
   proposalSendRequest.targets = this.endorsingOrgs.map((mspid) => channel.getEndorsers(mspid)).reduce(flatten, []);
}
...
...
// by now we should have targets or a discovery handler to be used
// by the send() of the proposal instance
const proposalResponse = await endorsement.send(proposalSendRequest);
...
```

In `send` method:

```
...
const signedEnvelope = this.getSignedProposal();
...
peer.sendProposal(signedEnvelope, requestTimeout)
...
```

Look inside `getSignedProposal` method:

```js
...
const fabproto6 = require('fabric-protos');
...
/*
* return a signed proposal from the signature and the payload as bytes
*
* This method is not intended for use by an application. It will be used
* by the send method of the super class.
* @returns {object} An object with the signature and the payload bytes
*/
getSignedProposal() {
    const method = `getSignedProposal[${this.type}:${this.name}]`;
    logger.debug('%s - start', method);

    this._checkPayloadAndSignature();

    const signedProposal = fabproto6.protos.SignedProposal.create({
        signature: this._signature,
        proposal_bytes: this._payload
    });

    // const signedProposal = {
    //  signature: this._signature,
    //  proposalBytes: this._payload
    // };

    return signedProposal;
}
```

So, try to use `fabric-protos` lib to encode your proposal. Hope this help

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I saw the only way to use the `fabric-network` is for the user to send the private key to our backend, and that is something I want to avoid for security reasons.

Comment: You can have public backend with user password and private d-app with operator user with certificate

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by moving to `@hyperledger/fabric-gateway` library. It works fine and has a well documented API. Offline transactions are better supported too.